# Mysql Table Relations - Migrations LARAVEL

Tags: mysql, laravel, migration

I am Creating my migrations with laravel, and I have this doubt:

I have these 2 tables:

```
Cars: ID || || BRAND_NAME || MODEL || YEAR

Brand: ID || NAME
```

So, if I would like to save `Brand ID` in my table `Cars` I use something like that:

```
$table->integer('brand_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('brand_id')->references('id')->on('brand');
```

All info it saved with a form and it works now. But if I would like to save `BRAND_NAME` instead of `BRAND_ID` in my `Cars` table. It's possible? How I can do this?

Comment: You just don't want to have `BRAND_NAME` in your `Cars` table.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel but, yes I want! Is not possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you are specting something like:

```
$table->string('BRAND_NAME');
$table->foreign('BRAND_NAME')->references('NAME')->on('brand');
```

Then the answer is no unless your Name field in brand is indexed.

I beleave it is useless to store the name if you are using the brand id on Cars table, but I think the only way to do this is to make a query to get the brand name before you save the car model, something like:

```
$car = new Car;
$car->brand_id = 1;
$car->brand_name = Brand::find(1)->name;
$car->save();
```

You can keep your model as it is right now and use the hasOne relationship in Car model, so you can get all brand realted data to each car model. To do this you just need to add in you car model class a method like:

```
public function brand()
{
 return $this->belongsTo('App\Car'); //<--- Put your car model path there
}
```

With that you can retrieve your Car model with all related brand data with something like:

```
$user = User::where("id", "=", 1)->with("brand")->first();
```

Check more info about relationships in https://www.laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships

Comment: A foreign key doesn't need to reference the primary key. But the referenced column(s) must be indexed. And the correct `brand()` relation is `belongsTo('App\Brand')`

Comment: Your are right. Answer edited to clarify. Thank you.